# How to draw a graph using python

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a list of value need to be drawn. The problem is have a format. How can I draw a graph with this kind of value. Im using python 2.7 with wxPython.

[This is the link to the value, I cannot paste it here because the format will change](http://pastebin.com/9yHV1V7i)

Comment: I assume you mean represent the data inside a graphical chart.
=> You need a tool to actually MAKE the chart before you can insert it inside your wxpython window.
What you want to used is called matplotlib. It creates figures and graphics from data.

It can be inserted into wxpython GUIs quite simply:
If you are familiar with WxPython you can try to adapt this simple example :
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/wx_mpl_bars.py.txt
disclaimer : not my work but very good example.

Answer (score 0):

The wxPython project has a separate demo package you can download and install. Get that and look at the PyPlot demo. It can most simple plots just fine. If you need something more powerful, go download matplotlib. They have an example on their website for integrating matplotlib with wxPython. There is also an article or two on the wxPython wiki about matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

you can use matplotlib
there's lot of examples how embedding matplotlib figure in wxpython